# $ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^m} \sum_{l=km}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^l} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^m} \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{kn}} $?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I don't find my mistake. Here is the situation: I have to calculate a certain probability. The solution is :

$$ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^m} \sum_{l=km}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^l} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^m} (\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{l}} -  \sum_{l=0}^{km-1} \frac{1}{2^{l}})\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^m}(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{km}}}{\frac{1}{2}}) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^m} \frac{1}{2^{km-1}} = \frac{2}{2^{k+1}-1} $$

But I have:

$$ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^m} \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{kn}} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^m} (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{kn}} -  \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} \frac{1}{2^{kn}})= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^m}( \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^k}} - \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2^{km}}}{1-\frac{1}{2^k}}) =\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^m}\frac{ \frac{1}{2^{km}}}{1-\frac{1}{2^k}} = \frac{2^k}{(2^k-1)(2^{k+1}-1)}.   $$

So could it be that $ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^m} \sum_{l=km}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^l} \neq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^m} \sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{kn}} $ ? or where is my mistake?

Comment: The sums are not the same. The left hand side includes, in the inner sum, terms with exponents not divisible by $k$, while the right hand side doesn't. More terms, larger sum.

Comment: When $k=1$ then, of course, they are equal. Otherwise, as your computation has shown the two sums are not equal. So, what is the issue?

Comment: Hello @JackyChong I was not sure if this sums are equal. It would have been possible that I made a mistake somewhere else. But thanks to Wojowu I know that the mistake is right at the beginning. :) I know that this question is a little bit short. Sorry about that. I can delete it, if this question is unnecessary.